# Prove that: $2^a+3^b<3a+4b$

Tags: inequality

Let be $a, b$ in $(0,1)$ such that $a+b>1$. I need to prove that:

$$2^a+3^b<3a+4b$$

I'm looking for an elementary proof that doesn't resort to the calculus tools.

Comment: Are you allow to use the fact that $2^a + 3^b$ is convex? Then you just need to check at the end-points $(a,b) \in \{ (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$.

Comment: @Willie Wong: yes. This idea came to me too late.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the graph of the function $f(x)=2^x$ we see that on interval $(0,1)$ it is bellow the line $y=x+1$ joining the points $(0,f(0))=(0,1)$ and $(1,f(1))=(1,2)$.
Thus we have 
$$2^a<1+a$$
for $a\in(0,1)$.

Using similar argument for $3^x$ we get
$$3^b<1+2b$$
for $b\in(0,1)$.

Adding the two inequalities together and using $1<a+b$ we obtain
$$2^a+3^b<2+a+2b<2(a+b)+a+2b=3a+4b.$$

Answer (score 3):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), $2^a \leq 1 + a$ and $3^b \leq 1 + 2b$. Therefore,
$$2^a + 3^b \leq 2 + a + 2b < 2(a + b) + a + 2b = 3a + 4b$$

Comment: Oh dear, just realized its the same as the above answer. *embarassed*

Comment: The problem is that both proofs use calculus in a hidden way ;) Proving Bernoulli for $a \in (0,1)$ requires calculus, and so does the concavity of $2^x$....

Comment: That is true, but I think convexity of $2^x$ can be established without calculus. $2^{\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y} = (2^x)^{\lambda} (2^y)^{1 - \lambda} \leq \lambda 2^x + (1 - \lambda) 2^y$ where the last step comes from the generalized AM-GM inequality.

Comment: True, but as far as I know, the generalized AM-GM inequality can only be proven for rational powers without Calculus ;) Anyhow, your point is probably as much non-calculus as possible for this problem...

Comment: @N.S. I was expecting some catch-22 like that :-). But then, we can use the fact that for f(x) continuous, it is enough to show midpoint convexity (thus using AM-GM in a rational power setting). Of course, to show f(x) is continuous we may have to resort to calculus again :P